# Make an extensible footer

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to make a footer that is similar to the footer of JavaScript column of JSBin in case of error:

(Before expanding)
[image]
(After expanding)
[image]
Precisely, it satisfies:

1) it is always at the bottom of the page, no matter how big the main body (that raises the error) is

2) It can be expanded when users click on it, and be collapsed back...

I have written the following code ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/puseniv/4/edit?html,js,output)), which shows the footer, and cannot be collapsed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      #footer {
      background-color: #FA8072;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="ms-font-m">
    the body
    <div id="footer">
      footer_line_1<br>footer_line_2<br>footer_line_3
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to make it extensible and collapsable?

PS: I also list the css files I have to use for other purposes, they might be useful...

Comment: What’s the exact problem with your current code?

Comment: The current code always expands everything... I want to make it be able to collapsed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your number of errors is about to get big, you can add **scroll** support, so that footer wont cover all of your page - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9at8wkdd/)

```js
$("#show").click(function() {
  $("#shoowDiv").toggle(500);
});
```

```css
 #footer {
   background-color: #FA8072;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
 }
 
 #shoowDiv{
   display:none;
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow-y: auto;
 }
#show{
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body class="ms-font-m">
  the body
  <div id="footer">
    <p id='show'>7 errors</p>
    <div id='shoowDiv'>
      <ul>
        <li>Issue #1</li>
        <li>Issue #2</li>
        <li>Issue #3</li>
        <li>Issue #4</li>
        <li>Issue #5</li>
        <li>Issue #6</li>
        <li>Issue #7</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: And same question as I asked for the first answer: is it possible to add the small triangle and make it change when collapsed/expanded? Additionally, why the collapsing/expanding action is quite slow?

Comment: @SoftTimur i corrected the link to JSFiddle. As Thinker showed, icon can be toggled through toggleClass method

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can expand and collapse by using `toggle()` function.

```js
$("#show").click(function() {
  $("#shoowDiv").toggle(500);
});
```

```css
 #footer {
   background-color: #FA8072;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
 }
 
 #shoowDiv{
   display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body class="ms-font-m">
  the body
  <div id="footer">
    <p id='show'>3 errors</p>
    <p id='shoowDiv'>

      footer_line_1
      <br>footer_line_2
      <br>footer_line_3</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

the reason why toggle functionality slow is i mentioned the seconds for that like this

`$("#shoowDiv").toggle(500);`

If you want it to be fast, you can change the seconds

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy653bpL/31/)

Comment: I see... is it possible to add the small triangle and make it change when collapsed/expanded? Additionally, why the collapsing/expanding action is quite slow?

Comment: yes we can add the triangle and make it toggle and the reason why toggle is slow is i mentioned the seconds for that. Check the jsfiddle link above. Have edited with your small triangle :)